# Problems with mdf file. How to open it?

Tags: sql-server, mdf

I am trying to attach a .mdf file. I used the following code:

```
CREATE DATABASE Antonio
ON (FILENAME = 'c:\Users\asaponar\Desktop\antonio lon\ION_Data_Archivemarch.mdf')
FOR ATTACH
```

but I get the following message :

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Directory lookup for the file
>   "c:\Users\asaponar\Desktop\antonio lon\ION_Data_Archivemarch.mdf"
>   failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

For sure the file permissions are right.

**Anything else to check please?**

Comment: rights over the mdf file is missing !

Comment: You asked the same question [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558988/problems-with-attaching-a-database-in-sql-server-error-5133) and it was closed as a duplicate. So this is a duplicate of a duplicate!!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty i have checked but the problem still exists

Comment: @antonio: But you can't ask the same question twice!!! [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the account running the SQL SERVER service has complete rights over the *.MDF file you are about to attach!

Answer (score 1):

Might be folder or file permission issue, try to move your .mdf files to Folder where your SQL server is located i.e.

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.<instance name>\MSSQL\DATA
```

Than login to Management studio as administrator or windows account, and try to attach.

Hope this will help!
Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Thank you very much it worked in that way...I still don't understand the reason but it worked :) . Also it created automatically an ldf file. Now i have other basic questions? How could i see the content of this mdf file? If I try simply to open it, in visual studio the database appears all messed up. What should i do next?

Comment: Location from where you was trying to restore Database was not accessible to SQL service, and by moving DB to service folder it resolve permission issue. For view Data you can't you able to see your tables? and does it not allowing you to view data there?

Comment: Maybe it does...and as well i don't know how to see them..If i click on tables in antonio database folder...a lot of files appears...but none of them look as simple table...but for sure i am wrong..

Comment: Hope this would help to understand how to use Management Studio http://tinyurl.com/oqosxly

Answer (score 0):

A litmus test is to copy and paste the file in file explorer. If you can do that, use the Windows authentication in SQL Server Management Studio to attach the file